# Zend Framework 2 view helper and controller plugin

Tags: plugins, zend-framework2, helper

I've been trying out zf2 for a couple of weeks and generally enjoy working with it. I have trouble though deciding where to do specific tasks. Does a function belong in the model or in the controller etc. 
At the moment I would like to understand the view helper and controller plugin concepts.
Could anyone give a few examples what kind of functionality belongs in a view helper?
I would like to know the same for the controller plugin, a few examples to make me understand why I would make a plugin instead of programming the functionality in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

View helpers extend functionality on the view layer and are for reusability throughout your application. 
Controller plugins extend functionality on the controller layer.

You generally use both to keep your controllers / views light and thin and reuse those in your application (keeping your code DRY).